# Initializing a final but not as an invar?

Tags: java, boolean, final

I've been working on an arcade video game and I need some help with the orientation of the bullets. Right now I have just one bullet which doesn't move, it is just drawn at where it would start(I'm doing everything step by step). The problem is that I don't know which way the bullet will go right or left. I have a boolean variable called bullet that turns true when the bullet is fired (when the X key is released).

```
    public void pistol( boolean right ) {

    if( right ) {
        dbg.fillRect( barrelRightX, barrelY, barrelWidth, barrelHeight );
        dbg.fillRect( handleRightX, handleY, handleWidth, handleHeight );
    }
    else {
        dbg.fillRect( barrelLeftX, barrelY, barrelWidth, barrelHeight );
        dbg.fillRect( handleLeftX, handleY, handleWidth, handleHeight );
    }

    if( bullet ) {

        if( right )
            dbg.drawOval( barrelRightX + barrelWidth, barrelY, 5, 5 );

        else
            dbg.drawOval( barrelLeftX - 5, barrelY, 5, 5 );

    }
}
```

The first block of code before if( bullet ) is just to draw the pistol. I put it there so you can see that right is a boolean parameter. Basically this means if the bullet has been fired and if the pistol is facing right then you would draw the bullet so it's looks as if it's coming right out of the barrel, and if the bullet has been fired and it's not facing right (which clearly means it's facing left) then you would draw it so it looks like it's coming out like it typically would. The problem is, since there's a huge animation loop that runs the entire program, when I fire a bullet and change the pistol's direction (right to left or left to right) the bullet changes location, which shouldn't happen. I tried making bullet final, but I need it to change for when it turns true when the X key is released. So, is there a way to sort of make it final but somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

`final` only says that a [member] variable cannot be re-assigned (or that a class cannot be extended and other stuff about methods ;-). It says *nothing* about *mutability* of objects. I also don't see its usage in the code...

In any case, why not just *create* a new Bullet [object] *when* the gun is fired? That is, the "direction" and "initial location" are aspects of the Bullet known when it is created. This allows [multiple independent] bullets to be spawned and dealt without fear of unwanted interactions... (1 bullet is just a particular case of N-bullets).

Comment: And be aware with bullets: Don't shoot yourself in the foot! ;)